# ATI video cards - unable to use entire monitor (1080p)

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, hdmi, 1080p

I have a Dell s2409w, 24" 1080p monitor.  With nVidia, I would plug-in the monitor and voila, it automatically knew it was 1080p (1920x1080).

I have both a Windows laptop and Ubuntu laptop.  Neither is capable of using the fullscreen even though the monitor reports the input is 1080p.

I am connecting the monitors via HDMI, is there a 'special' setting I am missing to make this work?

Otherwise, I like the performance of my ATI video cards, the drivers seem to be stable and reliable.

Thanks,

Walter

Comment: On the Windows laptop, have you tried manually setting the resolution using PowerStrip? http://entechtaiwan.com/util/ps.shtm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATI cards seem to interpret 1920x1080 HDMI as a TV mode and set an underscan of 15% by default.

I have connected up my HD3200 to both a 1920x1080 TV via HDMI and a 1280x1024 LCD via DVI and this only happens on the TV.

For some reason they hide this setting away as well.

In Windows you need to go to the `ATI Catalyst Control Center` and select the `Desktops & Displays` section.

Then use the dropdown menu from the triangle on the *small* screen icon at the bottom.

Select `Configure`, then the `Scaling Options` tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I may have to give that a try, perhaps this weekend, I'll try that.

Comment: That did it, took me a while to get to that.

Comment: Is there any way to do this globally?  Every time I switch resolution.. even to one I've already set, the underscan takes effect again.

Answer (score 1):

What model of ATI video card do you have?

It seems that with **driver release 9.10 of ATI Catalyst** they fixed some problem with **Overscan**/**Underscan**, I suggest you to update to latest driver release and see if it solves it.

http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/Pages/index.aspx

Comment: I am using an ATI Radeon Mobility 4650 HD.  I'll try the drivers again.

Comment: Nope - that didn't help anything.

Comment: I'm definitely going back to nVidia in the future.  Performance may not be as great for the price, but it always works in both Linux and Windows.  A few extra bucks is worth it to have a fully functioning external lcd monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the custom Radeon Mobility drivers at DriverHeaven.net?